# Database performance stats

Tags: sql-server, performance, profiler, trace

I have this request to collect some statistics on a database over a period of time.

1. Unique entries of the queries being run on a database from a application server ( Can be done with running a Trace )
2. For each query - be able to see its total elapsed time and amount of data transferred (in KB / MB, not number of records). ( Can also get total elapsed time from the trace per query ). But I am not sure how to find data transferred.

Is there a way to collect this data using profiler and perfmon.

Comment: I am sure you can set all of this up the SQL performance  profiler tool built into all SSMSE. The problem is setting up for first time can be tedious. Some more info here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/performance-monitoring-and-tuning-tools

Comment: I can get elapsed time with a trace filtering to the database and host name but how do i get the amount of data transferred between SQL and the application server ?

Comment: I am sure I have done this before -- but it was years ago.

Comment: This really is where a monitoring tool comes in. If this is for a single instance, compare the cost of a license for a tool that does what you want vs. the development and support time it would take for you to do it on your own. Plus, good monitoring software will have visualizations and analysis. It would take years to write that from scratch.